# Контроль одного экземпляра приложения C# в Linux

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono

Пытаюсь адаптировать виндовое C# WinForm приложение для работы в Linux. В Linux установлено Mono, т.е. запускаю прогу с его помощью. Для контроля за одним экземпляром приложения использовал такой класс:

```
public class SingleInstance :
        WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        public static SingleInstance app;
        private SingleInstance()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
        }

        public static void Run(Form_Log f,
            StartupNextInstanceEventHandler startupHandler)
        {
            app = new SingleInstance();
            app.MainForm = f;
            app.MainForm.Deactivate += MainForm_Deactivate;
            app.StartupNextInstance += startupHandler;
            app.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
        }  
    }
```

Но в Linux все равно запускается несколько копий приложения.

Как правильно организовать работу приложения в единственном экземпляре?

UPD

Тут возник еще вопрос. Возможно, мой код работает корректно, но я как-то неверно запускаю свое приложение. Сейчас запуск примерно такой: `mono MyApp.exe` (в терминале). Может есть какой другой более правильный способ запуска?

Comment: В винде это делается именованным мьютексом, будет ли оно в линуксе работать я без понятия. А ваш кусок кода вообще непонятно как относится к вашей задаче.

Comment: Насколько я почитал, мьютексы в Linux не катят, а мой кусок кода представляет собой механизм для контроля единственного экземпляра приложения. При повторном запуске вместо запуска приложения взводится событие `StartupNextInstance`.

Comment: @tym32167 Кусок кода относится к задаче, поскольку в нем используется класс WindowsFormsApplicationBase из VB, который действительно поддерживает single-instance (см. например https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.onstartupnextinstance?view=netframework-4.8). Что до мьютексов, то это лишь один из способов решения этой задачи. Как вариант, можно просто получить список процессов, и, если в нем уже есть процесс приложения, не запускать новый. Этот функционал должен быть и в Linux.

Comment: Проще всего сделать блокировку на своем файле который лежит в какой нибуть глобальной папке. По поводу мьютексов в mono есть интересная [заметка](https://aakinshin.net/posts/namedmutex-on-mono/)

Comment: @Vasek а можно немного подробнее по поводу блокировки? Не очень понятно как это вообще будет выглядеть.

Answer (score 1):

**Пример простой блокировки на файлах:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace EmptyConsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private static FileStream _lockFile;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!TryOpenLockFile(out _lockFile)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Приложение уже запущено");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            using (_lockFile) {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static bool TryOpenLockFile(out FileStream fileStream)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "MySuperApplication.lock";

            try {
                fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
                fileStream.Lock(0, 0);
            }
            catch (IOException) {
                fileStream = null;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```